# Issue with parfor in Matlab; "UndefinedFunction error thrown to workers" and Matlab crashing

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I've got some code that works perfectly fine in series, but I'm trying to speed it up by putting it in parallel, and it's giving me fits in multiple places. Here's my code:

```
parfor q = 1:num_ranges;
    timenumber = squeeze(DATA(q,:,:));
    timenumber_shift = circshift(timenumber, [0 1]);
    for m = 1:total_working_channels;
        timenumberm = timenumber(m,:);
        for n = 1:total_working_channels;
            R_P(m,n,q) = mean(timenumberm.*conj(timenumber(n,:)),2);
            R_V(m,n,q) = mean(timenumberm.*conj(timenumber_shift(n,:)),2);
        end
    end
end
```

DATA is a complex double of size 1716x32x400. When I try running it like this, Matlab just crashes ("Matlab has encountered an internal problem and needs to close"). Is the array too big to be sent? I have a feeling that that's the issue, but I'm not sure.

To get around that, I've tried changing the location of the parfor command; here's attempt #2:

```
for q = 1:num_ranges;
    timenumber = squeeze(DATA(q,:,:));
    timenumber_shift = circshift(timenumber, [0 1]);
    parfor m = 1:total_working_channels; %this is line 145!
        timenumberm = timenumber(m,:);
        for n = 1:total_working_channels;
            R_P(m,n,q) = mean(timenumberm.*conj(timenumber(n,:)),2);
            R_V(m,n,q) = mean(timenumberm.*conj(timenumber_shift(n,:)),2);
        end
    end
end
```

When I do this, Matlab doesn't crash. However, in the command line, it says "Analyzing and transferring files to workers...done.", followed by an error. Here's the error message:

Error using DBFCode12 (line 145). An UndefinedFunction error was thrown on the workers for ''. This might be because the file containing '' is not accessible on the
workers.  Use addAttachedFiles(pool, files) to specify the required files to be attached.  See the documentation for
'parallel.Pool/addAttachedFiles' for more details. Caused by: Undefined function or variable "".

I'm pretty well stumped on this one. Why is it saying there's an undefined function (with no name!) on the parfor line?

I'm using version R2014a.

Comment: Regarding your first question: yes, you might have a memory problem. SEGFAULT in matlab usually comes in the error you experience. Understandable: `R_P` and `R_V` seem to be of the same size as `DATA`, and their syntax doesn't seem to allow slicing for the interpreter. I'd wager that each of your nodes allocates `2*numel(DATA)*sizeof(complex)` memory for these arrays. Regarding the second: is `total_working_channels` a simple variable? Personal note: you don't need the semicolons after the `for` expressions, and I myself find them distracting. (I would've actually sworn that they cause errors)

Comment: @AndrasDeak +1 for semicolons guess

Comment: @HennadiiMadan thanks, but it would seem odd if it worked when the `parfor` was outside...none the less the error itself doesn't make much sense.

Comment: R_P and R_V are 32x32x1716 (so they're about 8% of the size of DATA). 'total_working_channels' is just a number (32).

Comment: I tried it without the semicolons, and it threw the same error, except now instead of '', it says '_colonobj'. Also, the last line of the error changed to "Undefined function '_colonobj' for input arguments of type 'int64' and attributes 'full nd real'."

Comment: Oooh sorry, you're right. I misread the `m/n` indices. Hmm. Well, you probably get the error at the line of the parfor because the pool hides the exact position where the worker died. The problem must be inside the loop then.

Comment: I don't like that error regarding "_colonobj" vs `int64` and `full nd real`: it would suggest to me that `1:total_working_channels` is not what it seems. Try changing that to literal `1:32` for now.

Comment: So here's something interesting: I decided to just run this snippet of the code (highlight and select 'evaluate selection'), and it works with and without the semicolons. It's slow (actually even slower than just running it in series...), but it does work.

Comment: "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"

Comment: @AndrasDeak so, it works, but only if I just run that section by itself. If I try to run the whole thing, I either get the above error or Matlab crashes. I have a few ideas about how to get it to run the whole thing. I'll try some of those tomorrow.

Comment: That sounds ***very*** odd. Frankly, I'm out of ideas. So let us know how yours work out:)

Comment: So I didn't change anything since yesterday, but now I've identified where the problem is coming from. If I run this script (DBFCode12.m) by itself, it runs fine, most of the time, and it's faster than running it in series. However, if I go to my driver script and just evaluate the line that says "run('/(path name)/DBFCode12.m');", Matlab either 1) crashes, or 2) throws the error described above at me. Now it's a matter of figuring out _why_! Either way, thanks for your help @AndrasDeak!

Comment: When you're saying "it runs fine, most of the time": exactly what happens when it doesn't run fine?

Comment: It crashed Matlab once or twice, although I think it may have been an issue with me not having the parallel pool set up properly.